# export rendert chart from tradingview using python

Tags: python, tradingview-api

I want to make a buybot for erc20/bep20 tokens. My customers want that I show the tradingview chart on top of the buy message.

Here is an example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihSKg.png

In the past I realized this with selenium: Simulate that I press around on the website and export the chart image. I dont want to make it with selenium anymore because it takes so many resources and is not that fast.

And here is my question: Is is possible to export the chart with python but without selenium?

An example chart would be this one: https://coinbrain.com/embed/bnb-0xa1611e8d4070dee36ef308952cf34255c92a01c5?theme=light&chart=1

Comment: it uses JavaScript to render plot (after getting data from server) so it needs browser (and selenium) to create it. Eventually if you can get values without using Selenium (maybe it send it as JSON data) then you could use some python modules (like `matplotlib`, `plotly`, `searborn`) to generate similar plot.